# Is this possible to show my own, custom ads on youtube video

Tags: ads

I have a question to know. And that is, is this possible to show my custom and own ads on youtube videos? I mean, any link or banner reffering to my own blog or website. I have searched it on google but din't find any result answaring my question. So I have asked it here on stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appericiated.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of.  The only options in your channel are on/off for their adsense units.   I imagine that if you get to `epic` status with them, you'll get an account rep who could potentially work with your own inventory.